# Apps script doGet return not the same date as on sheet

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am spotting some weird behavior in my Google Sheets / Apps Script. May be someone has already encountered this and have a solution?

I already checked my Spreadsheet Locale and Timezone setting to ensure that this setting is the same as timeZone setting in Google Apps Script.

`appsscript.json` file:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
    "access": "ANYONE_ANONYMOUS"
  }
}
```

I am pulling data from sheet `log` and use this data for a GET Endpoint from Apps Script.

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Date | Some data |
| 2 | 16/07/2022 | 2.34 |
| 3 | 17/07/2022 | 1.18 |
| 4 | 18/07/2022 | 4.16 |

My script:

```
function doGet(e) {

  try {

    const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('log')
    const data = sh.getDataRange().getValues()

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ success: true, data }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)

  } catch (e) {

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ success: false }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)

  }

}
```

This script will be deployed as a Webapp then Google will provide me with a link. When I do a GET request to this Webapp link, this is what I received:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        [
            "Date",
            "Some data"
        ],
        [
            "2022-07-15T17:00:00.000Z",
            2.34
        ],
        [
            "2022-07-16T17:00:00.000Z",
            1.18
        ],
        [
            "2022-07-17T17:00:00.000Z",
            4.16
        ]
    ]
}
```

When I read data from cell `A2` on sheet `log` with

```
function test() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('log')
  const data = sh.getRange('A2').getValue()
  
  Logger.log(data)
}
```

The result is:

```
Sat Jul 16 00:00:00 GMT+07:00 2022
```

I expect the date return from Apps Script Endpoint should be the same as date on sheet, but it is different. Am I missing something here?

I am currently using getDisplayValues to "pin down" the date as displayed on sheet and receive this date as string.

[image: google apps script image]

Updates:

Thank you all for your valuable time and information on this subject. With this information, I am able to switch from using `getDislayValues()` to `getValues()` to retain the underlying date value. And then after that in my internal system, I will process to local time accordingly. Example code in Python using `arrow` package:

```
import arrow

s = '2022-07-15T17:00:00.000Z'
arrow.get(s, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ').to('local').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```

or in JavaScript:

```
const s = '2022-07-15T17:00:00.000Z'
new Date(s).toLocaleDateString('vi-VN')
```

Comment: I'd try to avoid date objects and get them as strings with `getDispayValues()` instead of `getValues()`. It would be a more predicable approach.

Comment: Solutions should be added as answers, not as a question edit.

Answer (score 3):

`Sat Jul 16 00:00:00 GMT+07:00 2022` and `2022-07-15T17:00:00.000Z` are the same date in different timezone. `JSON` doesn't support timezones or date formats and they use `Z` zero offset `ISO8601` format to format them as strings. MDN says

> [The instances of Date implement the toJSON() function by returning a string (the same as date.toISOString()). Thus, they are treated as strings.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

> [The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z".](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Comment: Thank you Master, sorry for my ignorance. I have learnt something new today thanks to you. And I am able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are missing something.

`Logger.log` doesn't parse as string a Date object the same way that `JSON.stringify` does. Considering this, in order to make it easier to compare the output of your first script with the second, instead of

```
function test() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('log')
  const data = sh.getRange('A2').getValue()
  
  Logger.log(data)
}
```

use

```
function test() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('log')
  const data = sh.getRange('A2').getValue()
  
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data)) // Edited
}
```

In order to log the same value that is displayed on a Google Sheets cell, the easier way is, when reading the cell value(s), instead of using `getValue` / `getValues` use `getDisplayValue` / `getDisplayValues`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea how I can get the same date as on my sheet?

Comment: @ĐứcThanhNguyễn Answer edited (added one paragraph at the end).

Comment: yeah, I am currently using getDisplayValues for the task but want to have properly date for other task.

Comment: @ĐứcThanhNguyễn I suggest you to post a new question including [mcve] (not only a script, but one that include all the relevant tasks that should be done).

Comment: Thanks. By other task - I mean another internal closed-source system. So It's no use to do a minimal reproducible example. I already narrow down the problem to Date and JSON.stringify and updated my question with an image.

Comment: Hi Rubén, thank you for your time. I updated my question to add the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Date objects are tricky beasts. As far as I can tell in this case the dates you're taking from the sheet have internally GMT+0 timezone always. If you want to show them somewhere with another timezone you have to do it directly: to get the wanted timezone (from the curren Spreadsheet, for example) and convert the date object into a string with this timezone. Something like this:

```
function get_date() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var tz = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var date_obj = sh.getRange('a2').getValue();
  var date_str = Utilities.formatDate(date_obj, tz, 'YYYY-MM-dd');
  Logger.log(date_str);
}
```

Comment: I set the sheet timezone the same as apps script timezone (GMT+7)

Comment: It doesn't matter. The date objects have GTM+0 anyway.

Comment: Thank you Yuri, I am able to solve the problem with your information and I updated my question with it.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who doesn't want to deal with JS / timezone complexities and want to keep as much of the problem on the Google Sheet, here is a simple trick.

Imagine that on one cell you have the date. As the cell knows it is a date, when you click on it a calendar will appear.

[image]

Somewhere else you format that date as you wish (this could be done in the initial cell as well, but on my case I need it with 2 formats, so 2 cells).

Now here is the trick. If on the cell that your App Script will read you specify
**Format > Number > Plain Text**

[image]

When **App Script** reads that cell it will read **text** and **not a date**. So you App Script data will have exactly what you expect, that is, what you *see* on the sheet.

Note: The cell in orange has the formula `=TEXT(D5;"yyyy-mm-dd")`